# Accessing a global variable to others activities is not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access a variable as global variable to other activities but it is not making access.

One of my activities is **AriesActivity**, where i created variable as Global

```
public class AriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String time ="";
```

and the other activity is **MainActivity**, where I am trying to access the above mentioned variable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //print KEY_HASH for facebook
    printKeyHash();  }

public void taurus(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaurusActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    time="today";
    sign ="taurus";
    FatchedData fatchedData=new FatchedData();
    fatchedData.execute();
}
```

Here's in MainActivity a red color is showing over

> time="today";

Comment: Have you tried importing it

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be doing this.  Using static variables to pass data between activities is a strong code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the class name and then the static variable.
edit

```
 time="today";
```

to this code:

```
AriesActivity.time="today";
```